# How to map a dataframe with a dictionary using a function?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to apply a function while mapping a dataframe with the key's from a dictionary

```
col1 col2 
foo 0 
baa 1 
wen 2

dict: {
'foo':a,
'baa':b,
'wen':c
}

def function(value1,value2):
    return value1+value2
```

**output**

```
col1 col2
fooa 0
baab 1
wenc 2
```

thanks

Comment: Why not define `def function(value1): return value1 + mapping[value1]` instead, then you can use `df['col1'].map(function)` which should be cleaner.

Comment: Side note: don't use `dict` as a variable name. Doing so overwrites the built-in [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) function, which can lead to nasty hard-to-trace bugs in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df["col1"] =  df["col1"].apply(lambda x: x + (dict[x]))
```

Should do the trick

.apply will let you apply a function to the whole column, and you can make a fast, anonymous function with lambda. Here's the docs on this: [pandas.Series.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html)

Comment: thanks! In case of the key's of the dict doesn't match exactly, but they are really close, is there a way to apply the levenshtein distance? https://pypi.org/project/python-Levenshtein/

Comment: Yes, I've used a function for this as there's a bit more going on than above:

```from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

def distanceText(x):
    for i in list(mydict.keys()):
        if fuzz.ratio(x, i) >= 75:
            x = x + mydict[x]
            return x

df["col1"] = df["col1"].apply(distanceText)```

then you can change the fuzz ratio cut off (75 above) depending on how close you need the string to match.